# Работа с файлами HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, файлы

Создаю программу и надо решить проблему:
В программе есть окошко для выбора текстового файла, код:

```
<h1>Выберите файл!</h1>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="selectFile">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="selectFile">Choose file</label>
        <a class="btn btn-info" onclick="loadFile()" role="button">Загрузить</a>
    </div>
```

А потом вступает в силу JS и он должен принять этот файл и достать его вместимость, то что написано внутри этого файла. Мой код:

```
        const fs = require('fs');
        function loadFile(){
        var input = document.getElementById("selectFile").value; 
//смотрел в инете, value использовалось для принимания данных из формы input 
        fs.writeFileSync('TEST', input); 
//это мне для наглядности чтобы проверить что он принял
        }
```

Но я принимаю путь к этому файлу, смотрел в интернете на что можно поменять value чтобы дотянуться до содержания файла и безуспешно. Сможете помочь?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function loadFile(){
  // files - объект типа FileList
  let files = document.getElementById("selectFile").files; 
  
  // Перебираем все файлы 
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    // file - объект типа File
    file = files.item(i);
    console.log(file.name);
    
    // Получаем содержимое файла в виде текста
    file
      .text() 
      .then(text => {
        console.log(text);
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Выберите файл!</h1>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="selectFile">Choose file</label>
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="selectFile" onChange="loadFile()">
    </div>
```

[FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileList)

[File](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/File)

Comment: Возвращает ошибку files.text is not a function. Пока не могу понять как исправить.

Comment: а сам объект file получен? Имя файла выводится в консоли?

Comment: Имя да. Я взял file.path, через которую достану тот же файл, только уже чисто через JS.  Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В вашем коде используется `fs`, но это Node.js модуль, его нету в браузере. В браузере нет возможности работать с файловой системой напрямую, но можно в начале загрузить файл, а затем предложить заново сохранить его.

Пример загрузки файла и чтения его содержимого с помощью [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

```js
function onFileLoad(event) {
  const input = event.target;
  if(input.files.length > 0) {
    readTextFromFile(input.files[0])
      .then(text => {
        document.getElementById('text').value = text;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err)) 
  }
}

function readTextFromFile(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result)
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
        reader.readAsText(file)
  })
}
```

```html
<h1>Выберите файл!</h1>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" onChange="onFileLoad(event)" class="custom-file-input" id="selectFile">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="selectFile">Choose file</label>
    </div>

<h1>Result</h1>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

**Дополнение**

В связи с новой информацией по вопросу добавляю пример для `node.js`

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function main() {
  try {
    const text = await fs.readFile("f:/test.txt", 'utf8'); // читаем текст
    console.log(text); // выводим текст
    await fs.writeFile("f:/text2.txt", text); // сохраняем текст в другой файл
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

main();
```

Данный пример работает на `Node.js` начиная с версии 10, на более старых версиях `fs.promises` экспериментальный функционал и не работает без флага.

Документация [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) и [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Comment: Так да, я работаю с Node.js. Это всё пишу не для браузера, а для программы. У меня задача написать обфускатор, но сейчас разбираюсь как взять код из файла и потом записать в другой файл.

Не могу сейчас именно достать содержимое текстового файла для манипуляции ним.

Прошу не осуждать за меня за такие вопросы перед написанием целого обфускатора, ведь просто я студент и учусь всё это делать :-) .

Comment: @EgorMarunchak Так будете обфусцировать на стороне сервера или в браузере? В примерах выше показано как получить контент файла в браузере. Если вы собираетесь обфусцировать содержимое на сервере, то это совершенно другие методы

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, я делаю программу по видео на ютубе, где используются node.js и electron. Внутри для визуального представления интерфейса программы, используются HTML и CSS. Поэтому думал что можно будет свободно использовать теги html. Если я не прав, то поправьте как лучше сделать. P.s. Но варианты "Не правильно, но работает" тоже сойдут :).

Comment: В дополнении Вы написали код для чтения файла по пути к нему, но код HTML где можно выбрать файл возвращает путь "С:/fakepath/TEST.txt", из-за этого я не могу его использовать для чтения JS. Надо как-то взять файл на компьютере, открыть его и содержимое передать в JS код.

Comment: Дополняю к своему комментарию. Поигрался с кодом из другого ответа и достал путь к этому файлу. Спасибо за Ваши кода.

Comment: @EgorMarunchak скорей всего надо будет разделить программу на фронт (с html и javascript) и бэк (нода, слушающая запросы на локалхосте). Отправлять файлы из фронта POST-запросом на бэк